# RDP Timeout Using Libreoffice Impress on Pop!_OS

Tags: raspberry-pi, libreoffice, pop-os, rdp

I am connecting using RDP a raspberry pi 400 to a desktop, both running Pop_OS, the pi running 19.10 and the desktop running 22.04. Everything is fully updated. I am using Remmina to manage the connection.

There is a timeout occurring while controlling Libreoffice Impress, the slideshow in presentation mode will timeout to a black screen on the pi only. Which suggests it is a RDP timeout with Impress. The connection comes back after the slideshow is out of presentation mode. I have Impress' allow remote control checked enabled as well. I can not find anywhere about how to edit the timeout settings anywhere concerning RDP or Libreoffice Impress. What is going on?!

The timeout occurs between 1:30 - 1:40 minutes period of inactivity if that helps.

I have lots of experience with bash so the more technical explanations are welcomed.

Comment: Does it happen if you run libreoffice with hardware acceleration disabled?

Comment: Good idea, tested it and it did not work.